# GPU Profiling and callbacks in OpenGL ES

Tags: android, opengl-es, profiling, opengl-es-2.0

Is there a way to add callbacks in OpenGL ES similar to what DirectX has? I'm trying to profile the GPU performance, so I'm trying to figure out how long it took to execute certain parts of the GPU.

Ideally, I "push" a marker/callback, then call a bunch of GL draw calls, then push another marker, and then find out how many milliseconds passed inbetween those two markers a frame later.

(Any other ways to profile GPU performance would be helpful too.)

Comment: Good question. I've just been wondering that myself, I'm guessing "GL says no" on this issue.

Comment: @Justicle: That would be a big omission. I've seen code for fences in some extensions, but nothing I could immediately use for profiling. I'm holding out hope that there is something.

Comment: This isn't an answer since I'm not aware of anything for this on the Android side. However, PowerVR provide PVRTune under NDA and Apple have announced a GLES profiler in the next set of their tools. gDEBugger ES would be the correct tool on Windows, so that'd be a good way to look for bottlenecks in general. But presumably you want something to run on actual hardware?

Comment: @Tommy: That's correct. The code is currently specific to the target platform. I wouldn't be able to run it somewhere else, and the key is to profile the performance of the actual hardware.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

GPU maker provides nice profiler for Android. As far as my experience, it requires root privilege.

- [ADRENO™ PROFILER](http://developer.qualcomm.com/showcase/adreno-profiler) for Qualcomm Snapdragon
- [PerfHUD ES](http://developer.nvidia.com/tegra/perfhud-es) for NVIDIA Tegra2

Comment: Unfortunately those don't cover the phone I'm using, but those are great links anyway! I suppose there simply is no built-in way to profile the GPU via user function calls. As such, I assume that this is the best answer I can get. +60!

Comment: "[Imagination announces POWERVR Insider SDK 2.8 - Release v2.8 of the POWERVR Insider SDK includes: access to a new version or PVRTune,](http://www.imgtec.com/News/Release/index.asp?NewsID=618)" I can't wait!

Comment: PVRTrace and PVRTune are now out and available for all platform....look up the utilities page here : http://www.imgtec.com/powervr/insider/powervr-utilities.asp

Answer (score -1):

Use the [DDMS](http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/debugging/ddms.html) feature under your Eclipse environment. It's installed by default.

A Very powerful graphical profiling utility. You can also lookup threads, heap, method profiling, objects allocation, and more.

Check the how to use DDMS here.
Hope it helps ;)

Comment: See the other answer. I'm trying to profile the GPU, not CPU.

Comment: @EboMike Oups...I'm not very familliar with the whole profiling thing...just started doing it actually...sorry about that ;)