# Why is OpenGL rendering so slow with SDL2 on Android?

Tags: android, c++, opengl-es, sdl

I am porting a C++ 2D game to Android with the help of the NDK and the SDL; and I use OpenGL to render the sprites. The performances are quite disappointing.

After some investigations, I have found that the bottleneck is in the OpenGL calls during the rendering procedure. *Wait a second!* Before pasting the classic answer telling not change GL states, not to bind already bound textures and so on, please read the following.

Actually, even if I display a single 364x353 rgba texture in a middle of a black screen, it happens that the rendering takes almost 20 ms. The procedure can be summarized like this:

**Edit** The code below used to call `glFlush()`. As thokra pointed out in the comments, this is not necessary. Nevertheless, removing it did not improve the performances.

```
glClear( GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT );

glBindTexture( the_texture );
glEnable(GL_BLEND);

glEnableClientState( GL_COLOR_ARRAY );
glColorPointer( 4, GL_FLOAT, 0, colors );

glEnableClientState( GL_VERTEX_ARRAY );
glVertexPointer( 2, GL_FLOAT, 0, positions );

glEnableClientState( GL_TEXTURE_COORD_ARRAY );
glTexCoordPointer( 2, GL_FLOAT, 0, texture_positions );

glDrawArrays( GL_TRIANGLE_FAN, 0, vertex_count );

glDisableClientState( GL_TEXTURE_COORD_ARRAY );
glDisableClientState( GL_VERTEX_ARRAY );
glDisableClientState( GL_COLOR_ARRAY );
glDisable(GL_BLEND);

//glFlush();
SDL_GL_SwapWindow( window );
```

The execution of the last two lines of this function (flush and swap) is very irregular in duration. It can take from 4 to 12 ms!

The best hints I could find on the web are [this question on StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5165470/tips-for-improving-opengl-es-fill-rate-on-android) and this [thread on Google Groups](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/android-developers/dXkcKsv8fJM).

The answers to the questions on StackOverflow are of no help. According to the author of the question:

> clearing vs not clearing frame with glClear doesn't affect fps for me. Neither does enabling/disabling blending.

and

> […] just want to see if using compressed textures improves fill rate. It seems it doesn't […]

The Google Groups thread is very similar to my problem but it ended when the author gave up:

> So basically, there's no way to draw a 480x854
>   image on screen with OpenGL at 60fps because of the texel reading
>   bottleneck.

Seriously, no way? Why the call to both `glFlush()` and `SDL_GL_SwapWindow()` takes so long? And why is it so irregular? Can't I do anything about it?

I did a quick search in SDL2's source code and [found](http://hg.libsdl.org/SDL/file/54c06b0f65d9/src/core/android/SDL_android.c#l390) that `SDL_GL_SwapWindow()` uses the Java Native Interface to call a Java method which will do the work. Can it be the cause of the irregularity? What can I do about this?

Comment: The better question is, why flush in the first place?

Comment: Mmmh… I do not remember why the `glFlush()` call is here except that it felt like necessary a long time ago. Necessary like I could not see the sprites otherwise. Do you think I can throw it away? And Why?

Comment: glFlush will force commands up until this point to be executed as quickly as possible, effectively prioritizing whatever work whatever work you gave the GL before anything else. Usually GL implementations do a pretty good job of deciding what needs to be executed and when. Calling glFlush, you tell the GL what to do and thus limit the chances execution order is optimal. It's not as bad as glFinish which blocks until completion but still unnecessary in most applications. Also, if you don't see sprites, flushing isn't the solution. There's simply something wrong somewhere.

Comment: OK, I will try to remove the `glFlush()` and test as soon as I can to see if there are any differences. Nevertheless, [OpenGL documentation on `glFlush()`](http://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man/xhtml/glFlush.xml) tells that "_all programs should call glFlush whenever they count on having all of their previously issued commands completed. For example, call `glFlush` before waiting for user input that depends on the generated image_". Thus I have some doubts on the actual results.

Comment: Well, this is where glFlush is so nicely specified: It may return even if commands issued before didn't yet complete. So, reliance on the results directly after calling glFlush is simply not safe. Relying on the results after glFinish is. The questions is: do you really depend on the commands having executed? I really don't see why you would be in your example.

Comment: "slow on Android" - is this across all devices and Android versions, or are you thinking about one specific model?

Comment: @thokra `glFlush()` is not relevant in the example but I would like the enemies to be well rendered in the final product, so the user can react properly. I will try this evening to remove it to see if it really matters. @MSalters It was tested on a Nexus 4 only.

Comment: @thokra no need to test finally, calling glFlush() before swap buffers is [a common mistake](http://www.opengl.org/wiki/Common_Mistakes#glFinish_and_glFlush) since I use double buffering.

Comment: @julien: I wasn't sure how buffer swapping is handled on Android. What's written in the Wiki is explicitly not GLES specific! We're OpenGL.org over there, not Khronos.org. ;) However, it is likely it still applies. Interestingly, the MSDN API reference for SwapBuffers() only mentions flushing in the context of multiple threads.

Comment: @thokra, removing `glFlush()` had no effect. The call to `SDL_GL_SwapWindow()` takes 4 to 15 ms incrementally.

Comment: We recently updated SDL2 (after the 2.0 release) to use EGL calls directly, you may want to try that to rule out any JNI derived issues. The other thing I can think of is a vsync issue, see this for example: http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/16699/vsync-real-30fps-on-android (TL;DR: results vary with each device).

Comment: @gabomdq I have pulled the code of the repository as of 3rd of September and still have the issue. VSync seems to be a good candidate since the duration of the calls to `SDL_GL_SwapWindow()` vary in a repetitive way, in ms.: 4, 5, 6, … 15, 4, 5, 6, … 15, etc.

Answer (score -1):

I don't know if you are still doing it but try to consult Google for this matter. You will not get a rational answer from anywhere else on the web. 20ms is basically 50FPS. You mostly get like 250FPS doing those simple task you asked. What if, just what if, it is INTENTIONALLY LEFT OUT TO BE SLOW?

We used to code in simple intercept calls and used whole VGA card. But nowadays even in smartphones it is ran in something like VIRTUAL MODE. You need to get those DIRECT ACCESS to video chip in assembly or c level. Ask and consult google about this.